# Why multiple space remove from one string

Tags: javascript, php

[image]

I have code which stored in database and i am displaying in html form in php

I have tried preg_replace , nl2br and all that but still not getting predicted output.

Suppose i have string like

`this is the                  test`

```
$postContent = $getsingleviewodetail->epost_content;
$postContent = nl2br($postContent);
{!!substr($postContent,0,200)!!}
```

In the above sentence before test, we have many spaces, I want to display these spaces in my web page.

[image]

Comment: Add your  code here

Comment: i have added code

Comment: _“Why multiple space remove from one string”_ - because that _is_ how HTML handles whitespace under normal conditions. So you either need to format this differently (CSS `white-space`), or replace the spaces with non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Also show us the issue you percieve with the output to your page

Comment: Browsers collapse multiple spaces so if you want to display them, you need non-braking spaces `&nbsp;` or use a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<p>
this is the                  test
<br>
               this is the test
<br>
this              is the                  test
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working perfectly

in php

```
$string = "this is the                  test <br>test";
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#', "\n", $string);
```

in your view

```
<pre>{{$string}}</pre>
```

[image]

Comment: And that does WHAT?

Comment: The OP does not want to REMOVE the white space, they specifically want to KEEP it when shown on a web page

Comment: I have added screen sort in firebug also display space but in output remove space. why?

Comment: please use my answer.

Comment: This code remove space from between the and test.

my output is "this is the                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; test"

Comment: no i edited again. for now your output will be 'this is the                  test'

Comment: this working but br tag remove

please check link https://vdo.matrubharti.com/video/111129102/blog

Comment: @JigneshPrajapati please look my answer. did you check this one ?

Comment: Yes i checked but br remove and also space remove